# In Mint.com, can we run any SQL like queries?

Tags: mint.com

I've done some preliminary searching, but have not seen a way to perform the following search:

```
-Transaction by type (check/debit/credit)
-In a price range (ex: $100- $200)
-In a data range (ex: 1/1/2014 to 12/31/2014)
```

This would be simple to phrase as a sql transaction, but is it possible on mint.com?

Answer (score 2):

Mint doesn't offer such a facility, so not it's not possible